# How to read/modify a local file of HTML5 Local Storage from Python?

Tags: python, html, web-applications, local-storage

I did an [Ubuntu Webapp](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-webapps-telegram) and I'd like to create a Preferences dialog with a litte hack.

From the webapp I can storage/retrieve values with HTML5:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('showNotifications')) {
    // Enabling notifications...
}
```

I found this file in Ubuntu:

```
/home/costales/.local/share/Telegramzhukovgithubio/Local Storage/http_zhukov.github.io_0.localstorage
```

I'd like to launch an independent Python dialog with a few preferences (show notifications, autostart...), that python app reads/writes values in that file, then the webapp will read it and setting that configuration.

Is possible to read/write that values from the .localstorage file in Python? Please,how? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This worked :)

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/costales/.local/share/Telegramzhukovgithubio/Local Storage/http_zhukov.github.io_0.localstorage')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT key,value FROM ItemTable where key='count'")
print c.fetchone()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, costales. This helped me a lot! Note: under Windows 10 Chrome currently (version 55.0.2883.87 m) keeps its Web Storage files in this folder: "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\"